# jQuery - Uncaught TypeError: Object 0,0 has no method 'split' - Trying to split() on object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm just trying to split an `object` using commas as a delmiter. I know there is SOMETHING to split because when I output it by itself... it successfully says (over a loop) 1,1 and other numbers.

Here is a JSFiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/weka/5Xtwj/

If you remove these last two lines in the JavaScript section, it will work correctly because I am not wanting to get the `X` of the array.

```
var getX = path[index].split(",");
$("#debug").append("X: " + getX[0]);
```

PS - It is using this [pathfinding script](http://qiao.github.com/PathFinding.js/lib/pathfinding-browser.js) as an external library. But that isn't the problem.

Comment: There is so much wrong with your question ... What do you even want to do in your jsfiddle code?

Comment: Sorry, I did know you could split an object within an array. Sorry for asking a dumb question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **[split](http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/javascript-string-split.php)** with only strings, as you can see on your console.log it's an array of arrays, so that's why you're getting this error.
You can get the X value with the following codes:
Using **[slice](http://api.jquery.com/slice/)**:

```
var getX = path[index].slice(0);
```

Or:

```
var getX = path[index][0];
```

Comment: please note that everybody hates w3schools in here. Better change the [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) before anybody else notices. ;-)

Comment: Hmm ok I didn't know about it sry.

Answer (score 1):

Error message tells you

```
Object 0,0 has no method 'split'
```

It is an object [aka Array] and you are acting like it is a string. Why would you need to split it? Reference it.

```
var first = path[index][0];
```

Answer (score 1):

`split` can only be used on strings.  Each `path[index]` is *not* a string, it's an array (look at the console output).  You're seeing `0,0` because the array is being cast to a string for printing.

**Solution:** Instead of using `path[index].split(",")[0]`, just use `path[index][0]`.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The value of `path[index]` is not a string, it's an array.

You can't split it, and you don't need to. You can use it right away:

```
var getX = path[index];
$("#debug").append("X: " + getX[0] + "\n");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/5Xtwj/1/

Comment: You're thinking far too rationally for JavaScript. `typeof` returns 'object' for an Array. They are indeed actual Arrays ;-) But +1 for the rest of your answer.

Comment: @cliffsofinsanity: Oh, you are right. `path[index].constructor` actually returns the Array constructor. :) I corrected that.